# PIP install channels-> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, pip, channel

I am trying to install channels in Python 3.4 Django 1.10. But I encountered this problem when PIP installed twisted  ( in Windows 10)

```
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\link.exe /DLL /no
logo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\am
d64 /EXPORT:PyInit_raiser build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\src/twisted/test/rais
er.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\twisted\test\raiser.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.w
in-amd64-3.4\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-am
d64-3.4\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.pyd.manifest
    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\B
    in\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104
```

Is it because I have 32bit visual studio? Or there is not a Python c++ complier for Python 3.4? Any one has encountered and solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Changed to Python 32bit help...